# Swagger UI not getting generated for serverless Express api

Tags: express, aws-lambda, swagger, swagger-ui

My code structure is as follows-

```
src
 -handler.ts
 -routes
  --user.ts
serverless.yml
node_modules
..etc
```

Code in 'handler.ts' for is as follows-

```
import express, { Express, Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import serverless from "serverless-http";
import userRouter from "./routes/user";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
import swaggerJsDoc = require('swagger-jsdoc');

const app: Express = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

const swaggerOptions = {
  swaggerDefinition: {
    info: {
      version: "1.0.0",
      title: "User service",
      description: "user service APIs",
      contact: {
        name: "Sid"
      }
    }
  },
  apis: ["./routes/*.ts"]
};
const swaggerDocs = swaggerJsDoc(swaggerOptions);

app.use('/swagger',swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocs,{
  swaggerOptions: {
    url: "api-docs"
  },
}));

app.use('/', userRouter);

module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

After I deploy this lambda using the serverless, my APIs are working fine the swagger-ui URL is not working. Please help

Comment: How exactly is the Swagger UI URL not working? Does this URL return an HTTP error (e.g. 404 Not Found)? Or does it show an empty page? Or is the page displayed but shows some error?

Comment: I am not even getting a response code. I am getting this- Error: Exceeded maxRedirects. Probably stuck in a redirect loop http://localhost:3000/swagger/ (through Postman). And the webpage is showing - This page isn’t working

Comment: https://github.com/scottie1984/swagger-ui-express/issues/62#issuecomment-375478787 this helped me a lot